# jQuery - find out :hover-styles

Tags: css, hover, transition

I have a div which grows on hover. But: I applied a CSS-transition with 200ms.

Now, if I use the jQuery width()-function on hover() I get the wrong value because of the animation. But I need the hover-width in the endstate **at the exact hover-time, NOT at the end** (that's why setTimeout() doesn't solve the problem).

Is is possible to get a :hover-style as it is?

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="grows"></div>
</div><br><br><br><br>
<span id="width"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
div#parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

div#grows {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: black;

    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.2s ease;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}

div#grows:hover {
    width: 150%;
    height: 150%;
}
```

**And the JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#grows').hover(function() {
        var width = $(this).css('width')); // Is 100px but should be 150px!
    });
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v15h652h/

**EDIT**: maybe it's not clear enough: I need the width which is defined in the :hover-style **at the exact hover-time**, **NOT at the end**, then it's too late.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Check this [Link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end) try to apply that http://jsfiddle.net/v15h652h/3/

Answer (score -1):

Browsers have events allowing to handle the states of a CSS3 transition (or animation). You can use the `transitionend` one to wait for the transition to be finished to execute your callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div#grows').hover(function() {

    $(this).on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
      $(this).off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
      $('#width').html($('#width').html() + ' ' + $(this).css('width'));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
div#grows {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
div#grows:hover {
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="grows"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<span id="width"></span>
```

**PS:** I personnally prefer using the simple `.on()` event handler then `.off()` to remove it rather than Danko's `.one()` because the `.one()` will execute once for each event type that triggers (particularly, for Chrome, it will be executed twice)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but please read my question again: "But I need the hover-width in the endstate at the exact hover-time (that's why setTimeout() doesn't solve the problem)."